# How to apply different format or style to popup window

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

I display a popup window in a simple format. I want to apply different format of opening popup a window. How can I apply format or style so that it looks very good when pop window opens? The following is my source code:

HTML:

```
<div onMouseOver="show('healing')" onMouseOut="hide('healing')"> 
  <div id="healing" class="bgdiv" > 
    <div id ="title" class="Title"> Healing</div>
    <img class="img"  src="images/healing.bmp"> 
    <div class="description" >Welcome Sir.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#showhealing, #innovations, #div3 {
    visibility: hidden;    
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function show(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question correctly. But why don't you just use CSS to style?

Answer (score 0):

[PoeHaH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1478601/poehah) is right; you can style the popup using CSS. A good resource for learning CSS is the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn/css).

For example, try this in your CSS:

```css
#healing {
    visibility: hidden;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    background: grey;
}
```

The above will give the popup a blue border and a grey background. Not beautiful, I know, but it demonstrates the principle.

*By the way, there are some discrepancies in your code example (i.e. in CSS you have `#showhealing`, which has no equivalent in the HTML).*

Comment: i dont want to apply color my question is window of popup open different behaviour or format

Comment: @Maddy: Can you define "different behaviour or format"? Please update your question.

Comment: means i want to apply effect to popup window .for example transition of image . in that how image is display by using transition

Comment: @Maddy: You will have to change your question and make it more **specific**. What kind of effect do you need? What have you tried? For example, have you tried CSS3 transitions? If so, where did you get stuck? Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) for more tips.